# Running TomEE 7.0.3 on port 443 on Centos 7 server

Tags: security, port, tomcat8, tomee-7

We are running TomEE as the only webserver (ie not with apache).  I want to redirect all traffic to the secure site.  Everything works if I use port 8443 as the connector, but of course it displays the port number in the URL.  But if I edit server.xml and change the port number to 443, it fails.

server.xml has this:

```
Connector port=\"8080\" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" xpoweredBy="false" server="Apache TomEE" />}
```

...

```
Connector port="8443" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" maxThreads="100"
           minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
           enableLookups="false" disableUploadTimeout="true"
           acceptCount="100" scheme="https" secure="true"
           SSLEnabled="true" clientAuth="false"
           sslProtocol="TLS" keyAlias="server"
           keystoreFile=...hidden...
           keystorePass=...hidden... />
```

I did change both instances of the 8443 port number to 443

And the firewall settings are

```
firewall-cmd --list-all
public
 target: default
 icmp-block-inversion: no
 interfaces: 
 sources: 
 services: dhcpv6-client ssh
 ports: 3690/tcp 8080/tcp 8443/tcp 443/tcp
 protocols: 
 masquerade: no
 forward-ports: port=80:proto=tcp:toport=8080:toaddr=
 source-ports: 
 icmp-blocks: 
 rich rules:
```

Can anyone see why this is going wrong? Please and thanks?